# Gantt Chart in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gantt-chart

Do you know how to plot a Gantt chart in Matlab without using a third-party software? 
At the end I would love to obtain something like this:

[image]

What I was able to obtain so far is

[image]

using this code:

```
% Create data for childhood disease cases
measles = [38556 24472 14556 18060 19549 8122 28541 7880 3283 4135 7953 1884]';
mumps = [20178 23536 34561 37395 36072 32237 18597 9408 6005 6268 8963 13882]';
chickenPox = [37140 32169 37533 39103 33244 23269 16737 5411 3435 6052 12825 23332]';

% Create a stacked bar chart using the bar function
fig = figure;
bar(1:12, [measles mumps chickenPox], 0.5, 'stack');
axis([0 13 0 100000]);
title('Childhood diseases by month');
xlabel('Month');
ylabel('Cases (in thousands)');
legend('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Chicken pox');
```

That is not what I want but, maybe, goes in this direction

Comment: From SO rules: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: ...updating the question

Comment: I suggest `patch` and smartly choosen coordinates.

Comment: If you want to develop your own solution, I also strongly suggest working with [`datenum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) values whenever you are working with time and dates.

Comment: Your data doesn't have a set of tasks spanning a set of dates, so I'm unsure how you expect to display it as a Gantt chart - provide a desired output example which uses the same data as your current example data.

Comment: I will update, you are right

Comment: You also use [rectangule](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html). You only need to decide the x and y offset and the length of the rectangle for each entry.

Comment: can be a solution...but think how many lines to build a graph like the one in the figure :)

Comment: I have a quite easy solution. It is not the most elegant but works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Here, I share the solution I have just found (maybe it is not the most elegant one but it works for the purpose I have):***

*[the main idea is to draw a bar and "delete" the beginning overdrawing up on it another white bar]*

Let's say you have two vector:

```
start =[6907402; 2282194; 4579536; 2300332; 10540; 2307970; 4603492; 0];

stop =[9178344; 9168694;6895050; 4571400; 2280886; 4579044; 6897152 ;2271186];
```

There are 8 elements in each: every element is a task. In the `start` array, there is the start time of each task and in `stop` there is the end of the "execution" of a given task.

```
barh(stop)
hold on
barh(start,'w')
```

At the end here you have the Gantt:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

My scripts are evolved of course and, more, on the [matlab website](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/371898-plotting-a-gantt-chart-from-a-matrix), there is more information. Here 2 example more to complete the answer:

Option 1:

```
Positions=[1,2,3,4];
Gap_Duration=[0,2,5,3,5,3;
              3,5,3,5,3,4;
              9,3,0,0,12,2;
              13,2,2,2,8,3];
barh(Positions,Gap_Duration,'stacked');
```

[image]

Option 2:

```
Positions=[1,2,3,4];
Gap_Duration=[0,2,5,3,5,3;
              3,5,3,5,3,4;
              9,3,0,0,12,2;
              13,2,2,2,8,3];
barh(Positions,Gap_Duration,'stacked');
set(H([1 3 5]),'Visible','off')
```

[image]